# Encoding of App Extension in iOS NTAG Record

Tags: ios, nfc

Now that we have access to NTAG reading capability in iOS11beta, it appears that the only way to read the NTAG at the moment is to call up an NTAG capable app directly. 
This removes one of the biggest advantages of NFC - a deep shortcut into an App. 
There must be a plan to launch deep into a specific app in the encoding using an App Extension or similar. Has anyone discovered anything here regarding the encoding?

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience an nfc session can only started by an app.

Comment: That is my experience, too. But iOS NFC is work in progress. Is there a special reason why Apple will definitely not allow a global routing mechanism into an app?

Comment: It looks like this is still valid on iOS 11 Beta 5 and will be like this for next releases.